# How can I read comments from a Zip file?

Tags: java, zip

How can I read and write comments in a Zip file, using Java?

I can write comments with this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
zos.setComment("BMC Comment");
```

Comment: According to the [source](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/ant/ant/1.5.1/ant-1.5.1-sources.jar!/org/apache/tools/zip/ZipOutputStream.java?format=ok), the file comment is written at the very _end_ of the zip file.  There doesn't seem to be anything in `ZipInputStream` that accesses this data, but probably you could get it by just seeking backwards from the end of the file (manually).

Comment: Yeah... I just read icyrock link that use your method... I guess I don't have much choice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this post:

- http://www.flattermann.net/2009/01/read-a-zip-file-comment-with-java/

**Edit**: unfortunately the original link is now unavailable, here's a Web archive link:

http://web.archive.org/web/20100117212418/http://www.flattermann.net:80/2009/01/read-a-zip-file-comment-with-java/

For posterity, here's the gist (slightly formatted):

```
private static String getZipCommentFromBuffer (byte[] buffer, int len) {
  byte[] magicDirEnd = {0x50, 0x4b, 0x05, 0x06};
  int buffLen = Math.min(buffer.length, len);

  // Check the buffer from the end
  for (int i = buffLen - magicDirEnd.length - 22; i >= 0; i--) {
    boolean isMagicStart = true;

    for (int k = 0; k < magicDirEnd.length; k++) {
      if (buffer[i + k] != magicDirEnd[k]) {
        isMagicStart = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isMagicStart) {
      // Magic Start found!
      int commentLen = buffer[i + 20] + buffer[i + 21] * 256;
      int realLen = buffLen - i - 22;
      System.out.println ("ZIP comment found at buffer position " 
        + (i + 22) + " with len = " + commentLen + ", good!");

      if (commentLen != realLen) {
        System.out.println ("WARNING! ZIP comment size mismatch: "
          + "directory says len is " + commentLen
          + ", but file ends after " + realLen + " bytes!");
      }

      String comment = new String (buffer, i + 22, Math.min(commentLen, realLen));
      return comment;
    }
  }

  System.out.println ("ERROR! ZIP comment NOT found!");
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I just found that site just before you give in the answer... :) 
this is not a direct way to do it.. but It do the trick too ^^

Thanks anyway... I choose this as an Answer for now :)

Comment: Link is dead, would be nice to have the relevant part in the answer [:-(

Comment: What if the magic is part of the comment itself?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

`java.util.zip.ZipFile.getComment()`

Comment: Well, I missed that the OP wanted to read the single ZIP *file* comment, not a ZIP *entry* comment.